# Insert advertisement between entries from MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, mysqli

There will be 10 entries per page selected from database. How could I insert advertisement block inside list after 5 entries? Something like:

```
1. Lisa      New York        
2. Carl      Los Angeles     
3. Steve     Chicago         
4. Jennifer  Houston         
5. John      New York        

[ ADVERTISEMENT BLOCK ]

6. Paul      Chicago         
7. Andrew    New York       
8. Tom       New York        
9. Nicky     Houston         
10.Alex      Los Angeles    

[ NEXT PAGE ]
```

PHP code would be like that:

```
if (isset($_GET["page"])) { $page  = $_GET["page"]; } else { $page=1; }; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * $results_per_page;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY ID ASC LIMIT $start_from, ".$results_per_page;
$rs_result = $conn->query($sql); 

while($row = $rs_result->fetch_assoc()) {
?> 
    <ul>
        <li><? echo $row["id"]; ?></li>
        <li><? echo $row["name"]; ?></li>
        <li><? echo $row["city"]; ?></li>
    </ul>
<?php 
}; 

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(ID) AS total FROM tbl;
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$total_pages = ceil($row["total"] / $results_per_page); // calculate total pages with results
  
for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) {  // print links for all pages
            echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."'";
            if ($i==$page)  echo " class='curPage'";
            echo ">".$i."</a> "; 
}; 
?>
```

How could I display ad after 5 entries? Like that:

```
<a href="www.advertisement.com">
<img alt="test" src="test.png">
</a>
```

Comment: Damn normally I like to help but not with advertisment :D :P

Comment: but.. what about a if statement in your while and check if it's the 6th row and if yes add the advertisment block before? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
$advertisment_block = ""; //Here define your advertisment

$row_number=0;

while($row = $rs_result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $row_number++;
    echo ' 
        <ul>
            <li>'.$row["id"].'</li>
            <li>'.$row["name"].'</li>
            <li>'.$row["city"].'</li>
        </ul>';

    if(($row_number % 5) == 0) 
        echo $advertisment_block;
};
```

Comment: $advertisment_block and  $Advertisment_block are different. it will generate error.

Answer (score 0):

**Try This:-**

```
$i=0;
while($row = $rs_result->fetch_assoc()) {
if($i==5) { 
 echo "Your Advertisement";
 $i=0; //if you have rows more than 10 and you want to show advertisement block after every fifth row then need to reset $i to 0.
}
?> 
    <ul>
        <li><? echo $row["id"]; ?></li>
        <li><? echo $row["name"]; ?></li>
        <li><? echo $row["city"]; ?></li>
    </ul>
<?php 
$i++;
};
```

Comment: should, work, but maybe you'd want to reset $i in the if statement, sto futureproof it(20 rows, 4 ads for example)

Comment: Always use speaking variables and not $i or things like that.